# tezbox delegation change with babylon upgrade

Tags: delegating, tezbox

"Delegation has changed with the Babylon upgrade - you can now delegate directly from your tz* address. If you want to change your delegate, please transfer your funds to your tz* address and delegate from there. We will re-add delegation for KT1 addresses in the future."

This is the message that I get in my tezbox wallet. So I would like to send my tokens from kt to tz wallet. Can I do this? I already tried with 5 tokens but didn't get anything.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You should do this kind of operation directly using tezos-client.
You don't need to have a node rolling, you can inject operations to cryptium's node using `-A mainnet.cryptium.ch`

```
$ ./tezos-client -A mainnet.cryptium.ch withdraw delegate from KT1xxx
$ ./tezos-client -A mainnet.cryptium.ch set delegate for your_kt1 to baker_kt1
```

Comment: I em a total noob. What?